# Implementing a rich domain model in WCF where the Client objects act as remote facades

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, architecture

I'm working on a WCF project where I want to implement a RICH domain model where the client-side objects act as remote facades for server-side functionality but with certain shared aspects between client/server, such as validation. Let's say I have an Order class with two methods: Save() and Submit(). On the Server the Save() method would write to the database and the Submit() would send the order to a supplier's system.

I want to mirror the rich domain model on the client but instead of doing a database write in the Save() method, I want run the validation code and then call SaveOrder(this) on a WCF service interface. This would follow Fowler's Service layer + Domain model patterns. Ideally I want to write an AbstractOrder base class, implementing all shared functionality and specifying the abstract functions and then implement a ClientOrder, a ServerOrder and a WCF interface IOrderService(with Save(AbstractOrder) and Submit(AbstractOrder)) which acts as the service server-side. The ClientOrder's Save() / Submit() would call the Save/Submit methods on the IOrderService and pass itself during method call.

Is there a way to instruct WCF which objects to instantiate and deserialize the content into? I specifically want to work throughout my entire application with the Abstract version of the object and only upon deserialization figure out whether I need the Client/Server-side version of the object? We've already customized the WCF communication channels: we use protobuf combined with gzip compression for data transport between client/server and Ninject for service instantiation. Ideally I want to offload object instantiation to Ninject.

I specifically don't want the Order class to be a WCF service because I'm dealing with a fairly fat client where a large amount of logic is needed to keep the system perform within set limits and I preferably don't want to end up with an anemic domain model where most logic is stuffed into services.

In code it would like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOrderService
{
    [OperationContract]
    AbstractOrder GetById(int id);
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<AbstractOrder> GetBySupplier(int supplierId);
    [OperationContract]
    void Save(AbstractOrder order);
    [OperationContract]
    void Submit(AbstractOrder order);
}

public abstract class AbstractOrder()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AbstractOrderline> OrderLines { get; set; }

    public abstract void Save();
    public abstract void Submit();
}

public class ClientOrder : AbstractOrder
{
    public override void Save()
    {
        ValidateOrThrow();
        _service.Save(this);
    }

    public override void Submit()
    {
        ValidateOrThrow();
        _service.Submit(this);
    }
}

public class ServerOrder : AbstractOrder
{
    public override void Save()
    {
        ValidateOrThrow();
        _unitOfWork.Save(this);
    }

    public override void Submit()
    {
        Save();

        _supplierOrderService.Submit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have five paragraphs starting with an I. Anyway, if you want to share DTO types between WCF service and client, they are exactly the same type throughout the call stack. You could always introduce an IOrderService on that one Order class and set the IOrderService through a property. The class implementing that on the server will write to the database or call the other service, the one you set on the client will call the WCF service.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to transform my domain models into a DTO and then back into a domain model on the client. Fowler specifically writes that using DTOs in a local context can be harmful and making the API more difficult to use ( http://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html ). 
The idea is to transmit a ServerOrder to the client and deserialize it into a ClientOrder instance. We're using protobuf for (de)-serialization so I'm currently looking if it is possible to influence which object is created during deserialization, possibly by re-directing it to Ninject.

Comment: I'm aware that the WCF boundaries imply 'remoteness' but because our client/server applications shared large quantities of code we consider the communication between them as local.

Comment: My point is that the type you use at the server side is exactly the same type on the client side (and I called that your DTO, I did not propose introducing another one). So you cannot add behavior by inheritance; use composition instead.

Answer (score 1):

By default you cannot do this:

```
// Interface
AbstractOrder IOrderService.GetById(int);

// Service
AbstractOrder OrderService.GetById(int id)
{
    return new ServiceOrder(...);
}

// Client
ClientOrder = (ClientOrder)IOrderService.GetById(42);
```

Because the order that the service returns *is not* a `ClientOrder`. Using some reflection and a [custom formatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) you should be able to come a long way.

Alternatively, you could rely on composition, not inheritance. Introduce an `IRepository<T>` (or give it a name) in your shared code and create a property for that on your model:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Save(T model);
    void Submit(T model);
}

public class Order()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AbstractOrderline> OrderLines { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IRepository<Order> Repository { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (Repository == null) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        Repository.Save(this);
    }

    public void Submit()
    {
        if (Repository == null) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        Repository.Submit(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can inject the service- or client-specific logic thorugh this repository into your model:

```
// Client-specific implementation
public class ClientOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
    private readonly IClientOrderService _service;
    public ClientOrderRepository(IClientOrderService clientOrderService)
    {
        _service = clientOrderService;
    }

    public void Save(Order order)
    {
        _service.Save(order);
    }

    public void Submit(Order order)
    {
        _service.Submit(order);
    }
}
```

Then your service and client look like this:

```
// Interface
Order IOrderService.GetById(int);

// Service
Order OrderService.GetById(int id)
{
    return new Order(...);
}

// Client
Order order = IOrderService.GetById(42);
order.Repository = new ClientRepository(...);
order.Submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint towards using the IClientMessageFormatter. Gonna see if I can use that to off-load object instantiation to a DI container before handing it to the deserializer. If that doesn't work, I'll go the composition route.

Comment: Using a custom IClientFormatter / IDispatchFormatter to accomplish my original intention is actually quite possible. I do have to let go of Protobuf and instead go with Newtonsoft's Json as protobuf doesn't appear to have support for a DI container but its quite possible if I can figure out the exceptions generated by the WCF layer.

Comment: @Toolmaker cool, feel free to post your own answer if you've got it working.

Comment: I absolutely will, was planning on that once I got everything working nicely. Currently struggling with a few WCF exceptions on the server in the Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.BeforeRequest() method. What's the etiquette on Stackoverflow regarding further problems? Do I edit my original post and expand my question with further issues?

Comment: @Toolmaker no, that would change the scope of your question. Ask one question per isolated problem you encounter while trying to solve the problem in the bigger picture. Include a brief overview of what you're trying to do (perhaps a link to this question), show the relevant code, the exception and what you have tried to resolve it. :)

Comment: Thanks! I've posted the question (and paid special attention not to start every sentence with an I ;) ) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200774/using-a-custom-idispatch-clientmessageformatter-throws-outofboundsexceptions-i